# Angular2 SPA with WSO2IS

Tags: angular, wso2-identity-server

Is anyone familiar with an Angular2-seed or project which works with WSO2IS-5.x.0 for authentication?

What I would like to do is similar to the seed from Auth0:
https://github.com/auth0/auth0-angular2/

but instead of authentication towards the simple Express server in the backend, I would like to authenticate towards WSO2IS.

Alternatives to WSO2IS, e.g. OpenAM, are of course also of interest if there are Angular2-seeds/samples available for those...

Auth0 has a lot of good examples here: https://auth0.com/authenticate/angular2/ but I would like to explore other alternatives as well.

Comment: Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: I do agree and that is the reason why I initially contacted WSO2 with the same question. Instead of coming up with an answer, they pushed me to post the question here instead... Sorry for any inconvenience this might have brought you.